# Jave GUI for making a folder?

Tags: java, directory, jfilechooser

Greetings fellow programmers. I know how to make a folder in java (new File(strDirectoy)).mkdir();), but I was wondering if there's some sort of GUI similar to JFileChooser to make a new folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a folder to create, then I don't see (and that's quite a good question to my mind). But if you want to save a file and give the oportunity to create a folder to save it, then you can use the JFileChooser and call it in [save mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showSaveDialog%28java.awt.Component%29).

Comment: I found that you can set directories only for JFileChooser: chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);